# How to know if x509 certificate is signed by RSA?

Tags: java, ssl, rsa, x509certificate

What is the best way to know if any `x509 Certificate` is singed by RSA ?

What is mean is, by which file header can I know that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in yourcertfile.pem
```

The `Signature Algorithm` attribute will show you how the certificate was signed:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 13 (0xd)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=XX, L=XXXXXX, O=XXXXXX, OU=XXXXXX, CN=XXXXXX
        Validity: 
            Not Before: XXX XX XX:XX:XX XXXX GMT
            Not Before: XXX XX XX:XX:XX XXXX GMT
            ....
```

Comment: Ok, so there is need to be atleast the `rsa` value as a string inside of it ?

Comment: @gamil Yes, the `Signature Algorithm` attribute should include the hashing and encryption methods (sha1 and RSA in the above example). Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation how the text output is exactly formatted.

Comment: how can I recognize the RSA using the algorithm_id fields it self which is like: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11  ?

Comment: @gamil I am not very familiar with OIDs so you should cross check this comment. But according to http://oid-info.com you could check if your `algorithm_id` starts with `1.2.840.113549.1.1`. See  http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?tree=1.2.840.113549.1.1&see=all